# Can I ensure that a user enters an ip address in a form

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out how I can ensure that a user enters an ip address in an HTML form using PHP. I'm brand new to PHP ... I know in Python I can use regex. But, how can I achieve this in PHP, if at all?

form sample:

```
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="connection.php">
   <label>Login:
   <input type="text" name="ipaddress" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enter IP Address':this.value;" value="Enter IP Adress"/>
   </label>
   <label>
   <input type="submit" value="Connect"/>
   </label>
```

Comment: Don't forget that IPs are just 32 or 128bit numbers. `133169153` (decimal) and `0774000001` (octal) are exactly the same as `127.0.0.1` as far as TCP stacks are concerned

Comment: yes, PHP support regexp too, but your question could be solved by JavaScript?

Comment: ajreal, don't rely solely on client side validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://www.blog.highub.com/regular-expression/php-regex-regular-expression/php-regex-validate-ip-address/

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use PHP's filter_var function.

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Then use FILTER_VALIDATE_IP to validate the input.

example (returns Bool, TRUE/FALSE):

```
function isIP($ip)
{
 return filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, with HTML5 you can use the `pattern="([0-9]+\xe2){3}[0-9]+"` [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_attributes.asp) on the `<input>` with a regex to validate the field.

On the other hand, with PHP you can also use what Cory posted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`ip2long`](http://php.net/ip2long), as mentioned in the php manual:

```
<?php
// make sure IPs are valid. also converts a non-complete IP into
// a proper dotted quad as explained below.
$ip = long2ip(ip2long("127.0.0.1")); // "127.0.0.1"
$ip = long2ip(ip2long("10.0.0")); // "10.0.0.0"
$ip = long2ip(ip2long("10.0.256")); // "10.0.1.0"
?>
```

so, to check if the ip was correct, use the following code (thanks Puggan Se):

```
<?php
function validateIP($ip) {
  return $ip == long2ip(ip2long($ip));
}
?>
```

Comment: nope, will not work because of error handling.. just try somthing like `echo long2ip(ip2long("127.0.0.1xx"));`

Comment: so use: if($ip == long2ip(ip2long($ip))